# Recycler view with section header and reorder cells between the section header

Tags: android-recyclerview

So, just as question states.How to add section header in recycler view of android and also to reorder the cells of recycler view.

Comment: Can you just explain what you mean by "Section header" ? Also, how you want to reorder cells? on what basis?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMvBC.png). Refer this image for section headers. For reorder, I just want to shift one cell from one section header to another.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="Section 1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="item 1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#4d4949"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="#000" />
```

I am assuming what you are doing right now is to have an adapter layout for each cell, if you want to have headers, you should make your adapter layout look like above code,
you need to check for the groups in your Adapter class by whatever condition you have to check. By default the section header will be hidden for every cell, when your condition is met, you can make the header visible for a perticular cell and set whatever text you want as title.

Comment: This is working for me. Later I want to reorder or shift the list items from one section header to another. How can we acheive that?

Comment: you want to drag and drop?

Comment: Yes, something like that!

Comment: Does anybody has this answer of that??